# Square root of large PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, with $d\gg n$, typically $d$ is in the order of $10^5$ and $n$ in the order of $10$. I also have a matrix $X$. Both $W$ and $X$ are typically sparse. I need to operate on $X$ in the following 2 ways (in the computer):

1. $(I+WW^T)^{-1}X$
2. $(I+WW^T)^{-1/2}X$

The problem is that $WW^T$ is too large to fit in the computer's memory. For the 1st case, I can use the Woodbury identity and get $(I+WW^T)^{-1}=I-W(I+W^TW)^{-1}W^T$, and now I can operate on $X$ without the need to hold the $d\times d$ matrix $WW^T$ in memory.

My question is, is there some linear-algebra trick (factorization\identity\etc.) which I can use in order to deal with the 2nd case as well? I tried exploiting the 1st case, but with no success.

Comment: By $\,^{-1/2}$ are you reffering to the inverse of a Cholesky factor?

Comment: By $A^{-1/2}$ I mean $(A^{-1})^{1/2}$, and if $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, then so is $A^{-1}$, and for a PSD matrix, the square root can be (and usually is) defined by $UD^{1/2}U^T$, where $UDU^T$ is the diagonalized form, and $D^{1/2}$ is element-wise.